# Lambert W function multiplication with scalar

Tags: proof-verification, lambert-w

Let $W$ be the Lambert W function, $Y$ be a real valued function and  $x \in \mathbb{R} $.

Given $ Ye^Y = x \iff Y = W(x) $ is it true that $Y = kW(\frac{1}{k}x)$ for non-zero $k \in \mathbb{R} $ ?

I think this is true because:
$$
Ye^Y = x \\
\iff \frac{Ye^Y}{k} = \frac{x}{k} \\
\iff \frac{1}{k} \cdot Ye^Y = \frac{x}{k} \\
\iff \frac{1}{k}Y = W\left(\frac{x}{k}\right) \\
\iff Y = k W\left(\frac{1}{k} \cdot x \right) \\
\square
$$

Answer (score 0):

No this proof does not hold, because this step is completely unjustified without assuming the theory therefore this is just circular logic:
$$\iff \frac{1}{k} \cdot Ye^Y = \frac{x}{k} \\
\iff \frac{1}{k}Y = W\left(\frac{x}{k}\right) \\$$

The only way this step would be correct would be if the exponent ($Y$) was the same as the coefficient ($\frac1kY$)

A simple counterexample (let x = 5)
$$W(5) = 1.326...$$
$$2 W(\frac125) = 0.590...$$